# Apply coupon observer to set message in cart view

Tags: event-observer, coupon, cart-rule

I've created observer method for `salesrule_validator_process` event. How can I access coupon code and whole cart to check, if there are specific products in cart? If it found products with a specific criteria how to disable applying entered coupon?

Comment: Why just not to disable the products with given criteria in the shopping cart rile?

Answer (score 4):

The event `salesrule_validator_process` passes most of the objects that you are looking for.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('salesrule_validator_process', array(
    'rule'    => $rule,
    'item'    => $item,
    'address' => $address,
    'quote'   => $quote,
    'qty'     => $qty,
    'result'  => $result,
));
```

Here you have the quote (which is the cart). In your method your can call `$observer->getQuote()`.

You can then loop through the items attached to the quote and perform your checks.

Answer (score 3):

In your observer

```
public function myCouponObserver($event){
  //get quote
  $quote = $event->getQuote();
```

Get all item (parent)

```
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    //check for sku
    if($item->getSku() == 'xyz'){

    }
}
```

To get Coupon

```
$coupon_code = $quote->getCouponCode();
```

To remove coupon

```
 $quote->setCouponCode('');
 $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```